# SelectedItem Binding of ComboBoxes in ListBox not working TwoWay

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, listbox

I have a simple class `TestClass` that contains a property string `Rep` and implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

```
public class TestClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String rep;
    public String Rep
    {
        get { return rep; }
        set { rep = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public TestClass(String name)
    {
        Rep = name;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

My `Window` has a `ListBox` with a `ComboBox` as a DataTemplate.
In my `Window` class I create two `ObservableCollections<TestClass>`. One is supposed to be the `ItemsSource` for the `ComboBox`es in the list and the other should be where the items which the user selects via the `ComboBox`es get stored.
It's important that the items in `Items` are references to the items in `ComboSource`.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<TestClass> items;
    private ObservableCollection<TestClass> comboSource;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;

        ComboSource = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>();
        ComboSource.Add(new TestClass("4"));
        ComboSource.Add(new TestClass("5"));
        ComboSource.Add(new TestClass("6"));

        Items = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>();
        Items.Add(ComboSource[0]);
        Items.Add(ComboSource[1]);
        Items.Add(ComboSource[2]);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TestClass> Items 
    {
        get { return items; } 
        set { items = value; } 
    }
    public ObservableCollection<TestClass> ComboSource 
    { 
        get { return comboSource; } 
        set { comboSource = value; }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
  <StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Height="200">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ComboBox Width="50"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ComboSource,
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Rep"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I'm initializing `ComboSource` with three `TestClass` objects and then put these objects in `Items` as well.
What I want is that when the user selects e.g. the item with Rep `5` in the second `ComboBox` in the list, it should replace the reference on the second position in "Items" as well.
For some reason on startup the `SelectedItem` binding seems to work fine as it looks like this but when I select another item in the `ComboBox` it doesn't update the `Items` list.

[image]

EDIT:
Here is an image that should clarify what I'm trying to achieve. What I meant with *references* is that I don't want `Items` to contain two different `5` objects but just two *references* to the same object in `ComboSource`.

[image]

Comment: Why would selecting an item in the ComboBox "replace the reference" in Items? This makes no sense at all I am afraid. Please clarify your requirements.

Comment: I added some further explanation and an image to my post. I hope that makes things clearer.

Comment: @alektron, well, it's a bit hard to understand you needs... `Items` should only store a "history" of selected values in the left ComboBoxes? If it is, why do you fill it with 3 items at the beginning by hand? Or you only want that a ComboBox in the right list shows exactly the same SelectedItem of the correspondent ComboBox on the left, row by row?

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus The image doesn't show two different lists. The right side is what it should look like after I clicked the 5 (blue) on the left side

Comment: @alektron ok, where is your code that add the selected items into the `Items` list? Don't you expect WPF to add it magically, do you?

Comment: That's exactly the problem. I'm trying to bind selected Item somehow to Items but I can't get it to work